# Trying to make a button hover when cursor is over it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Image of Unity screen and inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOX19.png)

So I am trying to make a button larger upon a mouse hover. I wrote the code similar to what I found in a YouTube tutorial but it is not working. I believe I have the button setup correctly in the inspector but it is not working when I hover over the button.

```
public class Hover : MonoBehaviour
      {
 
     public void PointerEnter()
     {
         transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.5f, 1.5f);
 
     }
 
 
     public void PointerExit()
     {
         transform.localScale = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
     }
         
 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the methods name to "OnPointerEnter"/"OnPointerExit". Otherwise it could be that the Image would not scale up with the size of object.
Therefore get the image reference and scale it directly:

```
private Image playButton;

public void Start() 
 {
     image = GetComponent<Image>();
 }
public void PointerEnter()
 {
     image.transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.5f, 1.5f);

 }


 public void PointerExit()
 {
     image.transform.localScale = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement `IPointerEnterHandle` / `IPointerExitHandler` like e.g.

```
public class Hover : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandle, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData); 
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.5f, 1.5f);
    }
 
    public void OnPointerExit(EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData); 
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

and don't use the `EventTrigger` at all.

---

Alternatively you could also directly inherit and overwrite e.g.

```
public class HoverButton : Button
{
    public override void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        base.OnPointerEnter(eventData);
        
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.5f, 1.5f);
    }
    
    public override void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        base.OnPointerExit(eventData);
        
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

*Note though: Since the `Button` has a special Inspector you will not be able to expose any fields to the Inspector unless you implement your own custom editor inheriting from [`ButtonEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEditor.UI.ButtonEditor.html).*